# Не работают метки для break/continue в C#

Tags: c#, циклы

Почему не работает метка для continue в этом коде?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере от [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/80018k64(v=vs.100).aspx), такая же проблема, выдаёт ошибку

```
var s = "";

Outer:
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
    s += "\n";
    s += "i: " + i;
    s += " j: ";

Inner:
    for (var j = 21; j <= 30; j++)
        {
        if (j == 24)
             {
             continue Inner;
             }
        s += j + " ";
        }
    }
print(s);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваша ссылка ведет на документацию по JScript :)

Comment: у вас пример с MSDN не на C#

Comment: Точно, вот я идиот) Получается в C# такой штучки вообще нет? goto не берём.

Comment: [нет](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue)

Comment: Тогда лучше, наверное, удалить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[goto Microsoft пример c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) /
[continue Microsoft пример c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue)/
[break Microsoft пример c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break)
**не рекомендуется использовать goto .NET**.
'break/continue' не является 'goto' вы перепутали C++/JScript с C#. не используется префикс декларации.

пример c#

```
for (var j = 21; j <= 30; j++)
{
     if (j == 24)
     {
          continue; // можно использовать break;
     }
    s += j + " ";
 }
```

пример c# 'goto' variant :

```
 for (var j = 21; j <= 30; j++)
 {
     if (j == 24)
     {
          goto mk;
     }
    s += j + " ";
 }
mk:
```

Comment: С goto он станет бесконечным))

Comment: @Sergged Я просто демонстрировал .) есть вопросы напишите

Comment: Чисто технически, топикстер перепутал не с C++, а с JScript - у него же ссылка на источник кода прямо в вопросе есть. Тем не менее,  такие вопросы стоит закрывать,  а не отвечать на них - вопросы, вызванные случайной ошибкой,  бесполезны для будущих посетителей.

Comment: Я согласен с вами но C++ тоже используется такой вариант. Может быть вы Закройте :) бесполезно вопрос...